# Adding extra fields to each document returned by Course.find() in Mongoose modal using middleware

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongoose-schema

How to add extra fields to each document while using 'find' operation on mongoose modal?

I have two Schemas 'Coure' and 'Rating':

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const CourseSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
    },
  }
);

const Course =  mongoose.model('Course', CourseSchema);

const RatingSchema = mnogoose.Schema(
    rated_course: {
      type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Course',    
    },
    rated_by: {
      type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User',
    },
  },
);

const Rating =  mongoose.model('Rating', RatingSchema);
```

So when fetching all Courses using
`Course.find({});`

I want returned document to have two additional fields
`total_rating` and `i_rated` (if current user has rated it or not).

using `isAuthenticated` middleware, I'm able to get current logged in user details from
`req.user._id`

So, my question is that Is there any method by which I can add these two fields in every returned object returned ( using some middleware if possible? ) and also to send req.user._id as additional detail to `Modal.find()` ( not as a filter ) for `i_rated` field.

I tried using pre 'find' middle ware but getting Query object as aspected

```
CourseSchema.pre(
  'find',
//  document: true, query: false }, this is causing middle ware to not execute
//  document: false, query: true }, this is returning Query object which I don't need
  async function (next) {
    console.log(this);

    next();
  }
);
```

Also how to access `req.user._id` here to add `i_rated` field?